# How much work would be required to repair this roof?

Tags: roof, joists

I'm looking to buy a new house that needs a lot of work doing (almost a complete renovation job, rewiring, plumbing, damp proofing etc). On the last visit I went up into the loft to see what work needed doing, and if the roof needed replacing or if repairs were possible instead.

I've uploaded pictures here... https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZIHN.jpg which will hopefully give you an idea of what state it's in currently.

I know there's obviously a poor work gone on here in the past, but I'm just wondering if it's repairable without getting a whole new roof, and how big of a job this would be.

Other information that might be of use:

1) Slight sag in the roof where all 4 colours meet (on the diagram in my pictures) above 'bedroom 1'.

2) I don't have pictures of the area above 'bedroom 2' due to access and safety concerns! So that to be ignored (if possible).

3) I notice there's a bow and split in the larger beam. Is it possible to secure this with a metal plate instead of replacing?

Let me know if any other information is needed and I'll add it as soon as possible.

Comment: Among other things, replacing the entire roof would be included in the list, that the house inspector you hired, will throw at the realtor to say "I want 50k off the sticker price".

Comment: Not sure I understand... are you saying this would need a complete new roof and It's not repairable? If so, what do you mean by "Among other things"? Based in the UK btw, I'm guessing your 50k is USD?

Comment: Are those bricks just stacked and holding up the roof supports?

Comment: @DMoore yes I think so. I know this will need to be addressed as it's ridiculous as it is, but this is above a proper wall, so would it just be a case of building these bricks up properly to support? I don't know how this is normally structured in this situation?

Comment: I would get an engineer - not just an inspector to take a look.  Also might not hurt to get a contractor to give you a quote on this too.  There are too many variables right now because this looks pretty old/maybe not near code.  I wouldn't just rely on a home inspector for this unless you know a lot of contractors that can fix the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Anything is repairable if you throw enough money at it. If you already owned this house having it repaired would be a consideration. A perspective buyer should have the current owner address this or the buyer should get an *extreme* discount.

A $100 inspection would provide you with a list, containing deserved discounts; the cost to replace bad wiring, plumbing; anything out of order. It's a bargaining chip, where the owner will probably fix what they can on the cheap or eventually agree to a reduced price. 50k(US) is a very rough ballpark for a roof gut, plus.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much a renovation job as it is though (my bad for not clarifying this) so the owner obviously wants to sell it for the buyer to do the work. Wiring, plumbing, and damp proofing all need to be addressed. It has working water and electrics (untested but will be rewired anyway) but that's about it. I'll be asking for discount to cover a full roof replacement, but could it be made safe for a lot less do you think?

Comment: Repairs to the roof would be much cheaper then a tear down. However it's the second most important surface in the house, after the foundation. You might be sorry down the road. Roof troubles *must* be thoroughly addressed before everything else. Recently, I came across this http://www.dfwinvestors.net/app/investortips/flip.php about flipping houses.

Comment: +1 re addressing it immediately and making sure it is either fixed right before you buy or the price reflects the cost involved in fixing it. Someone in my neighborhood discovered that the place they were trying to renovate both had structural issues in the roof AND was off the foundation... and absolutely nobody would touch either problem until the other had been solved. They wound up tearing it down and rebuilding from scratch.